# FFT bin with 0 imaginary part

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, fft

I'm doing a single precision FFT of 20480 samples of a single tone of 16K sampled at 1.024 Msps.

This is the octave code

```
t=cast((0:20479)/1024000,"single");
x=sin(2*pi*16000*t);
f=fft(x);
f(9921)
```

As you can see if you run the code, the 9921 bin (which corresponds to the 496K frequency) has 0 imaginary part. I don't see any other bin (aside from dc bin) with 0 imaginary part.

Why is that? What does it mean?

Comment: It’s probably just coincidence. The bin at `length(x)/2+1` is expected to be purely real, because of conjugate symmetry, it is its own mirror element.

Comment: Note that the value at position `10561` also has zero imaginary part, and in fact equals the value at `9921`, because the DFT of a real signal has Hermitian symmetry. Also, position `1` and position `10241` have zero imaginary part: the former because it is just the mean of the signal (the exponential reduces to constant `1`), and the latter because it is the mean with alternating signs (the exponential reduces to alternating `1, -1, 1, -1, ...`).

Comment: @CrisLuengo I'd understand if it was close to zero, at least as close as the rest of bins, which are very close, but not pure zero.

Comment: Things that are expected to be 0 usually end up being very small values because of rounding errors. Something in the FFT being exactly zero must be a coincidence.